# Data Parallelism with GPars

Tags: concurrency, groovy, parallel-processing, gpars

I found this example here [Data Parallelism](http://www.gpars.org/1.0.0/guide/guide/dataParallelism.html#dataParallelism_asynchronousInvocation)

```
GParsPool.withPool() {
    Closure longLastingCalculation = {calculate()}
    Closure fastCalculation = longLastingCalculation.async()
    Future result=fastCalculation()
    //do stuff while calculation performs …
    println result.get()
}
```

I find it a bit extensive. Is there a way to shorten it?
Maybe:

```
GParsPool.withPool() {
    Future result = calculate().async()
    //do stuff while calculation performs …
    println result.get()
}
```

Would that work?
If not, is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you'd need:

```
Future result = { calculate() }.async()()
```

Answer (score 2):

`calculate().async()` will launch `calculate` method immediately. 
I'd bet with

```
GParsPool.withPool() {
    Future result = {calculate()}.async().call()
    //do stuff while calculation performs …
    println result.get()
}
```

because `async()` returns a closure. I'm not sure if `({calculate()}.async())()` would be valid, i'll test that later